# Performance impact when update primary key with same value

Tags: database, oracle

At work I saw query will update table primary key with same value. Here is an example. What's the impact on database performance when I do -

```
update t set id=1,content='ccc' 
where id=1;
```

I would expect the index won't be modified since key value is same. However I believe it will use more resource than just update content column itself. Am I right?

```
Table t (id is primary key)
id content
1  xxx
2  yyy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you're right that the index won't be modified, since primary key (naturally indexed) column has the same value like its index.

And, this update

```
update t set id=1,content='ccc' 
where id=1;
```

is more resource-comsuming than

```
update t set content='ccc' 
where id=1;
```

because, updating an indexed column is slower than updating a non-indexed one.

> Example follows ...

```
SQL> create table a ( b numeric, c varchar2(50) );
SQL> set timing on;
SQL> insert into a(b) select rownum from dual connect by level <= 1000000;      
     1000000 rows created.
     Elapsed: 00:00:02.74

SQL> update a set c=ascii(b);
     1000000 rows updated.
     Elapsed: 00:00:46.72

SQL> commit;
     Commit complete.
     Elapsed: 00:00:00.03

SQL> truncate table a;
     Table truncated.
     Elapsed: 00:00:01.33

SQL> insert into a(b) select rownum from dual connect by level <= 1000000;      
     1000000 rows created.
     Elapsed: 00:00:00.80 

SQL> commit;
     Commit complete.
     Elapsed: 00:00:00.03

SQL> create index idx_c on a;
     Index created.
     Elapsed: 00:00:00.46

SQL> update a set c=ascii(b);
     1000000 rows updated.
     Elapsed: 00:01:53.12

SQL> commit;
     Commit complete.
     Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
```

Comment: That's what I expected. Do you know a way to demo it? My supervisor wants see hard evidence.

Comment: @LuyinSun ok,i've added an example my friend. By the way i've confused ascii function with chr, you may try this.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros. I got idea now.

Comment: Here is what my experimental looks like. It seems update primary key not necessarily costs more. I don't know why the timing is not consistant.

Comment: SQL> update test set content=content;
SQL> 
910000 rows updated
Executed in 32.23 seconds
SQL> commit;
Commit complete
Executed in 0.016 seconds
SQL> update test set id=id,content=content;
910000 rows updated
Executed in 22.418 seconds
SQL> commit;
Commit complete
Executed in 0 seconds
SQL> update test set id=id,content=content;
SQL> 
910000 rows updated
Executed in 27.55 seconds
SQL> commit;
Commit complete
Executed in 0 seconds
SQL> update test set content=content;
910000 rows updated
Executed in 24.242 seconds
SQL> commit;
Commit complete
Executed in 0 seconds

Comment: could you take a look at my question?

Comment: ok, i see "update test set id=id,content=content" is faster than the other as average. I also believe that the index of pr.key doesn't change and may improve performance of this update. I regenerated this SQLs and results didn't change(  "update test set id=id,content=content" lasts 00:00:22.07 while  "update test set content=content" lasts 00:00:42.30.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. I looked at the explained plan and the cost are the same. Does this mean we should always update key columns when we do update since it's faster?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154477/discussion-between-luyin-sun-and-barbaros-ozhan).